# Modifying k-means package in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

Is it possible to modify the notion of distance in the kmeans package?

I have cyclical data and want to use an alternative notion of distance as such.

Comment: There is no `kmeans` package. Do you mean the `kmeans` function in the `stats` package?

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25213524/489704)

Comment: R is open source, so are the packages, so *always* you can download the source code, change it and re-use it.

Comment: But note that k-means in R is written in C and Fortran, not pure R. Pure R code usually is too slow.

Comment: Beautiful jbaums, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

K-means *shouldn't* be used with other distances. It is **not a distance based algorithm**. K-means is optimizing the sum-of-squares. If you want a proper distance-based k-means variation, it is called PAM. **PAM is the proper way of using k-means with other distance functions**.

Because **the mean is a least-squares estimator**, it only optimizes sum-of-squares.

If you put a different distance function into k-means, it may stop converging. Here is a counterexample:

Consider absolute correlation distance. The two series

```
+1 +2 +3 +4 +5
-1 -2 -3 -4 -5
```

are perfectly negatively correlated, so they have absolute correlation distance 0.

Taking the mean of these two vectors yields

```
 0  0  0  0  0
```

for which correlation isn't really defined anymore. If you wiggle around the numbers slightly, you can avoid this definition gap, but nevertheless **the vectors are dissimilar from their mean**. Because the mean optimized squared deviations, and does not find the best-correlation center.

The point is the **mean**. If you want to use a different distance function, you also **need to substitute the mean function, too**. One possible choice is the medoid, which yields PAM (Partitioning around Medoids).

Comment: I mean yes, it can right?. If I am using the kernel trick and I want to use a more general inner product, rather than euclidean distance.

Comment: What is the meaningful transformation if I have day of week and hour of day Anony where I can then use Euclidean distance?

Comment: If you use a kernel, it must be consistent with the mean, too. Some kernels will work, others may not work.
More often than not, just cannot use k-means. But you can use PAM then sometimes. Otherwise, we wouldn't have PAM.

Comment: That's not really answering, right?

Comment: Well, you can evenly space 7 points for weekdays on a circle, and 24 points for the time. Makes two extra dimensions, and squared Euclidean is pretty much what you want to use then. But the result will still be quite meaningless, because 24 h != 7 days != whatever other attributes you have. It will work, you will get a result. But k-means also happily clusters uniform data into meaningless partitions.

Comment: Then it is four dimensions right?

Comment: Yes. But you may need to weight them appropriately, and differences *add* up. So `sunday 6pm` and `monday 6am` have a difference of 1 day *and* 12 hours suddenly; whereas `monday 1am` and `monday 11pm` have just 2 hours difference. You see, just embedding things into Euclidean space doesn't mean the output is meaningful...